# autoNumeric not formatted when submit form

Tags: jquery

when the input value set to 100.000,00 . I want value keep 100000 (without separator and dec) when submit form. http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

That's works when using autoNumeric 2.0 https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric/tree/master/autoNumeric-2.0
There is an option "unSetOnSubmit" change that to true:

```
$('.auto').autoNumeric('init', {unSetOnSubmit: true});
```

Comment: So, if that works, what's the question? :)

Comment: @Satugts instead of answering the question in the question you should have used answer section for that. Also, SO encourage such behavior if you think your question and answer is valuable for others.